# Showing a modal dialog using html option in SP2013 seems broken

Tags: 2013, error, modal-dialog, bug

In SP2010 you could easily show a dialog using a DOM node with something like this:

```
var test = "<div id='correspondence'>" + result + "</div>";
        $('body').append(test);

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
            html: document.getElementById('correspondence'),
            title: "Correspondence",
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true,
            autoSize: true
        });
```

In SP 2013 I cannot for the life of me get this working. All that I get is an error stating: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Below is the code I tried. Any ideas on how to get this working?

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', function() 
{ 
    var dlgOptions = { html:document.getElementById('correspondence'), autoSize: true, autoSizeStartWidth: 550 };  
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dlgOptions); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code snippet you have doubled the `'` around `getElementById`.

In the second code snippet you have forgotten the `html:` in front of `getElementById`

Edit after James comment:
If you are not using minimal download strategy, you do not have to use SOD.

Comment: You need `SOD` when you have minimal download strategy turned on.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert has said there are issues with the JavaScript.

However, I had problems as well and had to add the following code to the base of my page to load the appropriate SharePoint scripts. The Initialise Page is a JavaScript function which sets up the page.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ITSP.TaskForm.InitialisePage, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function(){});
```

Comment: It says `ITSP.TaskForm.InitialisePage` is undefined when I run that code. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Sorry this is just a javascript function which is called when the sp.ui.dialog.js is loaded. I use a function to initialise the page and setup various elements on the page. You could wrap your dialog code inside a function and then reference the replace ITSP.TaskForm.InitialisePage with your function.